# PHP: why can't I loop twice on mysqli_fetch_array() results?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm retrieving some data from a mysql database. There are two loops which uses the same result set.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($newsQuery)) {
     echo "<a href='news-article.php?articleId=" .$row["news_id"]."' class='list-group-item active'>".$row["news_title"]."</a>";
}
```

This loop ends with success. then in the same page I have the following loop.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($newsQuery)) {
    echo $row["news_content"];
}
```

This loop doesn't return anything even if there are content in the table. When I try it in the first loop. the content is displayed correctly. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Think about why the first loop ever *stops* in the first place!

Answer (score 7):

From PHP's **mysqli_fetch_array** [DOCS](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php):

> Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows for the resultset represented by the result parameter.

You are using a 'while' loop on `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($newsQuery)`

This means the loop will keep going untill `mysqli_fetch_array($newsQuery)` returns `NULL`.

This is the reason why you **cant** use that loop again, since mysqli has finished fetching the results and the `mysqli_fetch_array($newsQuery)` now returns **NULL** untill you make a new query.

Try populating a variable with the results first, then loop on that variable:

```
$results = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($newsQuery)) {
     $results[] = $row;
}

foreach ($results as $key => $row) {
    echo "<a href='news-article.php?articleId=" .$row["news_id"]."' class='list-group-item active'>".$row["news_title"]."</a>";
}


foreach ($results as $key => $row) {
    echo $row["news_content"];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

While it is best to avoid logic that results in looping through a result set twice, if necessary you need to reset the result set back to the start:-

```
mysqli_data_seek($newsQuery, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you already fetch the value of `$newsQuery` Try this code

```
//temporary save the news content into array
$content = array();
$x=0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($newsQuery)) {
 echo "<a href='news-article.php?articleId=" .$row["news_id"]."' class='list-group-item     active'>".$row["news_title"]."</a>";
 $content[$x]= $row["news_content"];
 $x++;
}
```

and if you want to retrieve it

```
//now retrieve it
for($y=0; $y<count($content); $y++)
{
 echo $content[$y]+"<br/>";

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm a lil bit new to php.

Comment: Did this code solve your problem?

Comment: $x is not being incremented anywhere, so $content will hold only the last value

Comment: Oh i Forgot to increment, i updated my answer

Comment: Yeah got an idea on what I'm doing!

Comment: Do you have any problem regarding this question?If you don't have, pls mark my answer. Thanks