# Trying to compare a value from the database from the url after the?

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a value from the database and compare it with whatever id href was set. But nothing happens.

```php
<?php
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "products";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT id FROM items";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id =  $row["id"];
        echo <<<EOT
                <br>
                <form action='index.php?$id' method="POST">
                    <input type='submit' name="submit" value="more">
                </form>
        EOT;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] == $row) {
            echo 'you clicked something from the database' . $id;
        }
    }
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Trying to eventually get a value from the database then individually show a description if the more href is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

your answer has a high time complexity you can easily make you 
`SQL` query

```
SELECT id FROM items WHERE id = ?
```

and if the rows number is `0` this is mean there is no record with this `id`
you can check row's number from `num_rows`

Answer (score 0):

You will **never** see "you clicked something from the database" message because you already fetched the result from your query in the first loop, check this question [why-cant-i-loop-twice-on-mysqli-fetch-array-results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482625/php-why-cant-i-loop-twice-on-mysqli-fetch-array-results)

An option is to save the result in an array to use it later in your second loop

```
//your first loop
$savedRows = [];
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $savedRows[] = $row;
    //the rest of your code
}

// ......
// your second loop
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    foreach($savedRows as $row) {
        if ($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] == $row['id']) {
            echo 'you clicked something from the database ' . $id;
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that if this is your actual code, you need to make the closing identifier of your herodoc `EOT;` **the first character on it's line**, otherwise the rest of the file will be part of this string